# How to merge Google Ads and Firebase data in BigQuery

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore

I want to report whole Google Ads campaigns, but there is problem:

- I can't report data from Google Ads because 100 events in firebase = 120-150 events in Google Ads (google support didn't help).

So I want report data in Google Cloud platform, where will be data from Firebase. There are all data except cost per campaign.

I tried to import Google Ads data to `BigQuery` and merge data with `Fire-base` data, but when I did it, each event has price from whole `campaign` price.

Can someone help with data merge? Or is here someone who has problem with Firebase -> Google Ads event tracking and solve it?

Answer (score 1):

For getting your data for both services into BigQuery, use the [BigQuery transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer) to pull all Google Ads data, then [link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512#) your Firebase project for your Firebase data. Once you have all the data and understand each field; taking in consideration the [schema for Google Ads reports](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transformation) and the export [schema of Gogle Analytics for Firebase](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512), you can merge or denormalized data as per the requirements using [ANSI SQL queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement).